# Table of contents without page numbering for everything below \section

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

**My question:**
How to make it so `\section` and `\part` page numbers stay on the table of contents, whereas subsections, etc. have no page numbering?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're employing a document class that is compatible with the `tocloft` package, the following solution may be of interest to you. (Just copy the lines from `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}` to `\renewcommand\cftdot{}` to the preamble of your LaTeX document.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\cftsubsecpagefont{\@gobble}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecpagefont{\@gobble}
\renewcommand\cftparapagefont{\@gobble}
\renewcommand\cftsubparapagefont{\@gobble}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\cftdot{} % no dot leaders either
    
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{AA}
\section{BB}
\subsection{CC}
\subsubsection{DD}
\paragraph{EE}
\subparagraph{FF}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works like a charm!